# How to include jQuery in AngularJS when using browserify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, browserify

I'm using node, gulp and browserify to get my JS-Files into the right order and manage modules. I have jQuery and AngularJS installed as node modules and require them when needed. Angular by default uses jqLite to handle DOM-Elements.

I know that when jQuery gets loaded before AngularJS, Angular will use jQuery instead of jqLite.

**But how is it possible to get Angular to use jQuery when using browserify. Or: How may one require jQuery to angular?**

Now I'm just doing `var $ = require("jquery");` and use it when I need it. But I'd like to have an Angular that will natively give me jQuery methods when doing  for example:

```
app.directive("dir", function () {
    return {
        link : function ($scope, $elem) {
            var a = $elem.width();//jQuery methods currently not available here
        }
    };
});
```

What I actually need to do:

```
var jQuery = require("jquery");

app.directive("dir", function () {
    return {
        link : function ($scope, $elem) {
            var jqElement = jQuery($elem);
            var a = $jqElement.width();//jQuery methods are available here
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You need to read up on external requires in browserify, they can be a bit mind bending until it finally clicks. https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires

Comment: Why not just load jquery using a script reference on the page as the very first script?

Comment: @Igor: That would work but I'd like to bundle all my scripts into a single file :) On the other hand I'm just really curious why such would not be possible to achieve with browserify and npm modules.

Comment: For external well known resources you should try to use a CDN. It has benefits like browser caching if its been loaded before (highly likely with jquery) and won't cost you anything with bandwidth.

Comment: A CDN is not an option as I'm writing a web app that will not have any access to the web. It just connects to a nodeJS server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim)

```
npm install browserify-shim --save-dev
```

package.json

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
},
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "$",
  "angular": {
    "exports": "angular",
    "depends": ["jquery"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, promising approach. I've installed browserify-shim and updated my package.json. Then I'm running browserify through gulp but nothing changed. Have I missed something?

Comment: There is an example https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/wiki/browserify-shim-recipes#angular-which-depends-on-jquery--angular-modules-installation-via-npm-and-napa

Comment: But it could be that with `browserify-shim` you need to specify a path to jquery like here https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/tree/master/examples/shim-jquery

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, thanks for your help. Unfortunately I still can't get this to work. My package.json looks like yours but after running my gulp task to browserify I still can't access jquery methods within my directives link function :(

Comment: Ah, thanks to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34813884/2577116) I realized that I still need to require jquery somewhere. I thought that browserify-shim will always include jquery whenever I require angular, but it seems that this is not the case. Anyway, now it works :)

Comment: This is weird because I thought `"depends": ["jquery"]` indeed should load jquery when you load `angular`. But I didn't test it. Good to now. Glad it works for you =)

Comment: @Abel there's no need to include in an edit some text that says you made an edit -- there's already [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36086341/revisions) for that.

Answer (score 2):

For AngualrJS 1.x use a value provider

```
var jQuery = require('jQuery');
var app = require('../app');

app.value('jQuery', jQuery);
```

Then in your Directives or Components where you need it (you shouldn't need jQuery):

```
var app = require('../app');

foo.$inject = ['jQuery'];
function foo(jQuery) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(element, scope, attr) {

             // I can use jQuery here
             // though I am unsure why
             // I would want to. 

        }
    }
}

app.directive('foo', foo);
```

Now if you need to write a Unit Test for this directive you can inject a stub for jQuery if need be.

Answer (score 0):

for angularjs this works for me.

```
var jQuery = require('jQuery');
var angular = require("angular");
```